# Jackson: Mapping dynamic JSON response

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm retrieving data from a rest service and I'm using JSON to map the JSON response to java POJOs. All works fine, except the service will return a different JSON result for invalid calls, which is not mappable to the POJO:

```
{
  "error":[
    {
        "code": 1,
        "message":"Parameter is invalid."
    }
  ]
}
```

UPDATE:
The response format for a valid call looks something like this:

```
persons: {
   personCount: 14
   person: [
   {
      firstname: "Michael"
      name: "Bolton"
   }
 ]
}
```

I'm mapping the response like this:

```
Person person = mapper.readValue(in, Person.class);
```

I've looked through the API and some SO and blog-postings, but I didn't find a hint on how to approach this so far. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: could you post an example of the json for successful responses?

Comment: I've updated my post with more data...

Comment: Does the server send a different HTTP status code for an error? Does it set different `Content-Type` headers for a valid and an invalid call?

Comment: Are you owning the service? If you can use everytime the same name for the root property (for example payload) instead of persons, customers, etc I have a solution

Comment: I cannot change the service, unfortunatly. The content-type is the same, but the status code is indeed diffent, so I can use this to stay with my current "static" mapping approach. My problem is solved, but still, is there also a way to tackle this in a jackson-way?